# Driving an LCD filter from a set of welding goggles - Optical modulator

Tags: lcd, photodiode

I bought a pair of LCD welding goggles in the hope that I could re-purpose the switchable light filter for another project. Unfortunately, the circuit driving the LCD filter is way above my ability to understand.

I did notice that the unit has two photodiodes that are used to detect the arc-light and trigger the filter.

I was wondering if there might be some way to 'spoof' the diode so that it switched the filter.  For example, shorting each of them out, or injecting current at the input or output.

Comment: Your title is misleading. You want to know how to replace a photodiode with some kind of switch, not "trigger" it. I would say replace it with a diode and switchable resistor in parallel. Values depend on the circuit.

Comment: So do you want it permanently transparent or opaque?

Comment: I do want to switch it as Eugene said (I will try to change the title). Ultimately I want to drive this from an Arduino so that I can switch a light source on and off. (I know it sounds weird - but I have a good reason ;-) )

Comment: @Eugene - thank you .. I will try to change the title

Comment: Can’t you just control an LED that is pointed at the diodes?  It will then also be isolated from your control logic. It will act like an opto-isolator.

Comment: @HandyHowie The led will probably have to be *very* powerful to emulate the arc.

Comment: @HandyHowie - That is certainly a good idea! I will try the experiment. I wonder if an LED would be bright enough given that this is meant to switch on with an arc - but definately worth an experiment!

Comment: @EugeneSh. Or very close. High brightness LEDs do sometimes come with safety warnings.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Maybe, but my welding mask can go dark just looking up at the lights in my workshop.  It may also have a sensitivity control on it,

Comment: This one does not appear to be particularly sensitive. In retrospect I may have chosen the wrong mask filter. I see that there are some others with test switches - which I think would have given me an easier solution. But I will try both of the key suggestions here (1) Switch using an LED input and (2) Scope the connection to the LCD itself and see if I can emulate that. Thank you all

Comment: why not use light? it's easy to use electricity to make light - just use an LED. I think the sensor want to see a bunch of pulses.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an oscilloscope available, check out the driving waveform on the LCD. I expect that it's just some simple AC squarewave, or modified-sine-wave (i.e. bipolar squarewave with deadtime), which you can duplicate with the Arduino PWM and a series capacitor.

Comment: Ah! Now that sounds like a good thing. Trully I would like to get rid of the whole driver circuit from the original goggles - since I suspect it has built in delay and hysteresis. So direct drive sounds good. I will put a scope onto the lcd. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A photodiode has the same properties with a diode , in absence of light it is essentially a diode.Make sure you dont let light into the photodiode and use it as a diode.

Comment: Thank you - but I am not sure what that would mean in practice. How would I 'use it as a diode'? What would I need to do to 'switch' the diode as if light was striking it?

Comment: A photodiode isnt a switch in the absence of light it behaves like a diode and in the presence of light and absence of external voltage it becomes a current source.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, yes, there is some way to emulate the operation of the photodiode in the circuit. However, without providing any other information (schematics, pictures, etc), nobody here will be able to tell you how. We can only speculate.

Photodiodes have two key modes of operation (photovoltaic mode and photoconductive mode) that require different circuit design. The resulting output may pass through an amplifier and then may be fed to a comparator to switch a digital input on the microcontroller, or perhaps it is fed directly to an ADC. If it is the former, you could simply replace the comparator circuit with a switching circuit, and remove the photodiode and related circuitry altogether.

As suggested by others, if you really have no ability to understand or communicate the operation of the circuit, the easiest thing to do would be to find an LED that produces light detectable by the photodiode and close couple it to the photodiode. The circuit required to power and switch that LED would be trivial.

Comment: thank you. That is helpful. I am afraid my electronics knowledge is rather basic .. I am a software engineer by trade and can 'understand' basic digital circuits, but this one is beyond me I am afraid.

Comment: You could try to probe the voltage on the pins of the microcontroller while turning your “arc-light” on and off. If you see that a voltage is changing between VCC and GND in tandem with your application of arc-light, that may be the input which triggers your desired LCD response. Note that there may be more than one, you mentioned multiple photodiodes. Examining the traces on the PCB from the photodiode through the other ICs or passive components to your controller may also offer a hint as to what pin to probe.

Answer (score 0):

Driving the glass directly is probably the best aproach.

Failing that (there may be a lot of reasons) one can always just short the photodiodes.

A peculiarity of these masks is that they react to changes of light intensity and not on particular intensity level. So you may want to pulse the photodiode short.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I am going to try to drive directly .. and also experiment with switching via an LED into the photodiode.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to all who commented above - this provided me a useful way forward.

I managed to drive the filter.  Here is a short video of it working: https://youtu.be/yZrTHgSHRUI

I followed the suggestions and scoped the input to the LCD filter directly. The result was unexpected (to me!) and interesting.

The input was indeed a AC voltage square wave, switching between +5.6 and -5.6 volts. The interesting part was the frequency, around 1Hz. I was expecting something like KHz, and was suprised to see the switching so slow.

The unit seems to behave like a charging capacitor: the current into the device drops to zero over a period of about 10ms.  That is, a short pulse of current as the square wave switches from +ve, to -ve and back.

After disconnecting the filter from its driver circuit I managed to test it by driving it directly from a signal generator, set to a 1Hz, AC square wave. The filter will switch to 'opaque' with voltages in the range +/-3v to +/-8v. The higher the voltage the more opaque the display.

I did, however, need to put a resistor in parallel with the display in order to 'clear' it - i.e. to return from opaque to transparent. Again, I think, an indication that it is acting like a charged capacitor.

I can't share my application for this device on account of it being TOP SECRET :-), but nevertheless, it is an interesting device that might have lots of creative applications.

Thank you again for all who provided useful help above.